# How to dynamically render/load my array with two values?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-react

I'm a beginner in Java Script and ReactJS and I'm doing a project to improve my knowledge.

I will render some polygonal points on the map, I am using the `google-maps-react` library.

I have a problem regarding polygons, to be able to plot on the map I must send the data in this way:

```js
const coords = {
  coords: [
    [
      { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.19 },
      { lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118 },
      { lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757 },
      { lat: 25.774, lng: -80.19 },
    ],
    [
      { lat: 25.774, lng: -60.19 },
      { lat: 18.466, lng: -46.118 },
      { lat: 32.321, lng: -44.757 },
      { lat: 25.774, lng: -60.19 },
    ],
  ],
};
```

The problem is that the coordinates that I have are in a different format. They are in this format:

```js
[
  [
    [-47.7027099655629, -22.26485424139211],
    [-47.70271526762656, -22.26487408404245],
    [-47.70272860122938, -22.26486817968162],
    [-47.70275769033151, -22.26485486960603],
    [-47.7027803963492, -22.26483968832534],
    [-47.7027099655629, -22.26485424139211]
  ]
], [
  [
    [-47.70336262481528, -22.26561084941619],
    [-47.70336542334331, -22.26561213882109],
    [-47.70336596593334, -22.26561211173161],
    [-47.7033695288571, -22.2656092720629],
    [-47.70337969579747, -22.26560034650085],
    [-47.70336262481528, -22.26561084941619]
  ]
]
```

As you can see, they are objects of different types, they know how to tell me if there is any javascript function where I can leave my array of coordinates in the same way as the model of the library `google-maps-react`?

**I would like my array to look like this:**

```js
const coords = {
  coords: [
    [
      { lat: -47.7027099655629, lng: -22.26485424139211 },
      { lat: -47.70271526762656, lng: -22.26487408404245 },
      { lat: -47.70275769033151, lng: -22.26485486960603 },
      { lat: -47.7027803963492, lng: -22.26483968832534 },
      { lat: -47.7027099655629, lng: -22.26485424139211 },
    ],
    [
      { lat: -47.70336262481528, lng: -22.26561084941619 },
      { lat: -47.70336542334331, lng: -22.26561213882109 },
      { lat: -47.70336596593334, lng: -22.26561211173161 },
      { lat: -47.70337969579747, lng: -22.26560034650085 },
      { lat: -47.70336262481528, lng: -22.26561084941619 },
    ],
  ],
};
```

There is no way for me to change this data one by one, the original file with my coordinates has almost eight thousand lines, so I need a function that does this automatically.

Here's my original data I trying to use: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bernalvinicius/6213d045e6f1c360008489bb416e58b5/raw/b8b997bb7e8d640a41a76ae0214663499fe1d8e5/coordinates.json

Thank you!!

Comment: You have to transform the data. You array map function for that

Comment: `coords={};
coords.coords=jsonData.coordinates.map(item=>item[0].map(function(coord){ return {lat:coord[0],lng:coord[1]}}));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's an array of arrays, you can use the function `reduce` along with the function `map` to be able to build the desired output.

```js
let arr = [  [    [      [-47.7027099655629, -22.26485424139211],      [-47.70271526762656, -22.26487408404245],      [-47.70272860122938, -22.26486817968162],      [-47.70275769033151, -22.26485486960603],      [-47.7027803963492, -22.26483968832534],      [-47.7027099655629, -22.26485424139211]    ]  ], [    [      [-47.70336262481528, -22.26561084941619],      [-47.70336542334331, -22.26561213882109],      [-47.70336596593334, -22.26561211173161],      [-47.7033695288571, -22.2656092720629],      [-47.70337969579747, -22.26560034650085],      [-47.70336262481528, -22.26561084941619]    ]  ]];
let coords = {
  coords: arr.reduce((a, [c]) => a.concat([c.map(([lat, lng]) => ({lat, lng}))]), [])
};

console.log(coords);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to map that data with a loop function. Since here you need to loop over multiple arrays I would suggest using a reduce function.

If you don't know what a reduce function is you should have a look here first: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp

Basically you loop over each element and you change the value. Here is a little example, you may need to adjust this if needed:

```js
const newCoordinates = coordinates.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const newCoordiantes = curr[0].map((coord) => ({
    lat: coord[0],
    lng: coord[1]
  }));
  acc.push([newCoordiantes]);
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-cloud-nfx4k?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method. You seem to have 3 layers of arrays within each other, and at the end you have an array with `[lat, lng]` that you want to change to `{ lat, lng }`, but also it seems you have one layer that just contains one sub-element which you want to flatten out. So you can cascade two `map` calls (one of them destructuring the single-element array implicitly) as follows:

```js
const convert = arr => arr.map(([group]) => group.map(([lat, lng]) => ({ lat, lng })))

const inputData = [[[[-47.7027099655629,-22.26485424139211],[-47.70271526762656,-22.26487408404245],[-47.70272860122938,-22.26486817968162],[-47.70275769033151,-22.26485486960603],[-47.7027803963492,-22.26483968832534],[-47.7027099655629,-22.26485424139211]]],[[[-47.70336262481528,-22.26561084941619],[-47.70336542334331,-22.26561213882109],[-47.70336596593334,-22.26561211173161],[-47.7033695288571,-22.2656092720629],[-47.70337969579747,-22.26560034650085],[-47.70336262481528,-22.26561084941619]]]]

const outputData = convert(inputData)
console.log(outputData)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Note that the input data that you showed had the format `[...], [...]` which in itself is not a full data structure (it would be two arrays joined by a comma operator, which doesn't make much sense). I'm guessing there should be an outer array around that (`[[...], [...]]`), which I added in my example (otherwise it wouldn't work).